# Form Validation not working as it should be

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to validate my form. Below is the jquery. When I click on submit button, if form has `<span class="error">` then it should alert faild if not alert success. The problem is it only alert 'Faild' whether there is `<span class="error">` or not. please look at in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbrYX/)

```
$(".submitBtn").click(function() {
            if($("form").find('.error')) {
                alert('Faild');
            } else {
                alert('Success');
            //return true;    
            }
});
$("form").submit(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        });

<form id=="subscribeForm" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="f-comp t1 name" />
                    <input type="text" name="age" class="f-comp t2 age" />
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="f-comp t3 email" />
                    <textarea name="detail" class="f-comp words"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitBtn" />
    <span class="error"></span>
                </form>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing a boolean operation.

Try this:

```
if($("form").find('.error').length > 0)
```

Notice that you're checking the number of items that match class 'error', instead of whether you get a return or not.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be checking whether the length of the jQuery returned is zero or not. As it is, the condition will always evaluate to true even if no elements are matched because a jQuery object is always returned.

```
$(".submitBtn").click(function() {
    if($("form").find('.error').length > 0) { //<<-- check for non-zero length
        alert('Failed');
    } else {
        alert('Success');
        //return true;    
    }
});
```

<sub>And "failed" has an *e* in it</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(".submitBtn").click(function() {
            if($("form").find('.error').size()) {
                alert('Failed');
            } else {
                alert('Success');
            //return true;    
            }
});
```

`.size()` will return a numeric number of elements matched. i.e. 0 if none.